# Horizontal rule inserted when refresh with cmd + R

Tags: feature-request, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

On Stack Overflow, when I ask or answer a question there is a 'control panel' above the text box.

[image]

Each one of the items is activated by either a manual click or a shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> for bold, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> for italic...). On FireFox, Safari and Chrome, there is a shortcut for refreshing the page (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) but on Firefox the <kbd>cmd</kbd> key activates the horizontal rule as well as using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Another example, <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> is a shortcut for either `blockquote` or quitting the entire browser.

Could we make it so that the text editor shortcuts aren't activated by using browser-global keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Doesn't happen for me in Safari. But fair request I guess

Comment: Doesn't happen on Safari because Mac applications use Cmd-based shortcuts, @Pekka, so our editor's Ctrl-based shortcuts don't conflict. What would you suggest that we use on Windows, James?

Comment: @CodyGray On windows is there a Ctrl + R to refresh shortcut?

Comment: Yes. Cmd+R on Mac, Ctrl+R on Windows (and lots of Linux desktop environments). I'm certain this conflict has been discussed before, but I didn't find it, even in a brief search on [Meta.SE].

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315159/why-are-the-editor-keyboard-shortcuts-not-documented/315183#315183

Comment: Amen. Related on MSE: [Overwrite ⌃-S and/or ⌘-S to save a question/answer edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/101406) [Keyboard shortcut for formatting posts on Mac should support ⌘](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78599) Although fn would be just as bad as Command, honestly: that's even _more_ of a system-level key.

Comment: I guess everyone knows, but a workaround would be to use the F5 function key to refresh instead, which will at least work on IE/Edge, Chrome, Firefox and Opera

Comment: I didn't even know about this! I just write `<hr/>`

Comment: @NickA in SO Markdown it's a triple dash `---` or triple underscore `___` after an empty line.

Comment: While I personally use F5, a web page overriding browser-global keyboard shortcut is, generally, a bad UX choice. While it's often a pain in the rear to find appropriate shortcuts that work across all browsers, keyboard shortcuts should either be chosen such that they do not conflict with already existing shortcuts in the host program (i.e. the various browser for a webpage), or should allow the user to define them to be whatever the user desires (at which point conflicts are the user's problem).

Comment: @Aaron F5 does not refresh the page in chrome on a mac so it does not work as a workaround for all cases.