# There should be hotkeys for switching between rendered view and markdown while reviewing suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, edits, suggested-edits

I now have the privilege to be able to review suggested edits.
On the page I now have two buttons to choose whether I want to see the post as:

1. Rendered output
2. Markdown

Which is very helpful. The thing that bugs me is that I have to click on the buttons when I want to switch between the two options.

Especially when I scroll down long posts, and need to scroll up to change the setting yet again.

A possible solution would be to have a hotkey to switch between the two.
I do not know if that would raise other issues.

Additionally it would be an intermediate solution to move the buttons along with the screen while scrolling.

Comment: Good suggestion. Another option is for the rendered output/markdown buttons to be fixed the same way that the Approve/Reject buttons are.

Comment: Good suggestion, but remember how few hotkeys there are left especially for mac users: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354881/horizontal-rule-inserted-when-refresh-with-cmd-r

Comment: True, there's probably other issues with hotkeys as well - hotkeys were just my first notion. I like the idea of having them fixed (as @KodosJohnson mentioned) too.

Comment: While waiting for SE devs to implement this feature (this may take forever), a workaround is always to make your own userscript...